# nginx deny all dont work for specific directory

Tags: nginx

the server is running nginx.

The access to all files in /meins/mymail is possible, but why?

regards 
Daniel

This is my config:

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www..de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www..de/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/www..de;

    index index.html index.php index.htm ;

    server_name www..de;

    location ~* /meins/mymail/
    {
            deny all;
    }


    location ~ \.php$
    {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$
    {
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$
    {
            expires 1m;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$
    {
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
    }

    location /images
    {
            try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location /deins
    {
            try_files $uri $uri/ ;
    }

            location /
    {
            rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/*([^/]*)/*([^/\.]*)/*.*$ /main.php?kkk=$1&aaa=$2&bbb=$3 last;
            rewrite ^.$ /main.php?kkk=Startseite last;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use `^~` rather than `~*` before `/meins/mymail`, to instruct it to match it as a prefix rather than a regex, but to not try any regexes if it matches, are you still able to access that dir?

Comment: location ^~ /meins/mymail/
        {
                deny all;
        }

Comment: ... also dont work... access is still possible

Comment: Just to make sure, you have restarted nginx, you are accessing the page over https on port 443, there are no other config files with location blocks for https:443, and you are using the same domain name as in the config file, right?

Comment: JackW you are right... other configs have override my settings... now it works...

Comment: You don't need to use regex here, `location /meins/mymail` prefix-matching is enough and faster.